# How to set condition for onclick validation javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing one small problem to set the message and clear the message.

I have 2 input where onclick of the button I should check the input fields satisfies the condition else don't show any message

OR

if error message was displaying after condition gets satisfied I should remove the message

but the code below doesn't satisfies if phnum is 10 digit and pincode is less than 7 digit and vise versa

if both field length doesn't satisfy on click of button i should display both the error messages

```js
const inputValidation = () => {
  if (phnum?.length < 10) {
    //phnum must be 10 digit(error message)
    if (picode?.length < 7) {
      //zipcode must be 7 digit (error message)
    } else {
      //remove  zipcode message
    } else {
      //remove phnum message
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan but i have to set error message if condition fails

Comment: ok let me try your solution, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move the clear errors before the ifs
2. Move the second if since now you only test picode if phnum is in error

```js
const inputValidation = () => {
  //remove  zipcode message
  //remove phnum message
  if (phnum?.length < 10) {
    //phnum must be 10 digit(error message)
  } 
  if (picode?.length < 7) { // removing the else will show both
    //zipcode must be 7 digit (error message)
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i enter both phnum and zipcode less than the length??
both message should display

Comment: Remove the else

Comment: you can use "if" instead of "else if", so you can check 2 variables then you can display 2 error code if happened.